# Pair with Raspberry Pi Zero using Bluetooth 2.0 dongle headless

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with a Bluetooth 2.0 dongle in the USB port, since it's Bluetooth 2.0 I can't use Simple Pairing Mode (only available on Bluetooth 2.1+). I'd like to pair my computer with the Raspberry Pi but the computer asks me for a PIN and I don't want to have to interact with the Raspberry.

Since Simple Pairing Mode is not available I thought of using a fixed PIN (like 0000) so that when the computer asks for a PIN I can input 0000 and it will pair the devices. However, I have not found a way to set a fixed PIN.

I've searched on the Internet but I could only found solutions for Bluetooth 2.1+ or using Bluez4 (I'm using Bluez 5.23-2+rpi2).

I've tried downloading [simple-agent](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/test/simple-agent) editing *RequestPinCode* to return "0000" as I've read somewhere that it would work, but then I run the code with:

```
python agent.py
```

And I get an error:

```
Illegal instruction
```

I also tried with:

```
sudo python agent.py
```

In this case I don't get an error, I get no output whatsoever, the program just exists.

I'm not sure how *simple-agent* works but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to wait on an infinite loop.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. All I want is to set a fixed PIN (0000) for the Raspberry PI so that I can introduce that PIN every time a new device wants to connect to the Raspberry PI via Bluetooth. I don't really care how it's done as long as it works.

**UPDATE #1:** I've tried the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233442/automate-bluetooth-pairing-trusting-in-bluez5) so I guess I was executing the script the wrong way, so I tried this:

```
./simple-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
```

Just like the answer said but it gives an error:

```
-bash: ./simple-agent: Permission denied
```

I tried with:

```
sudo ./simple-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
```

But then it says:

```
sudo: ./simple-agent: command not found
```

**UPDATE #2:** After giving executing permissions to the simple-agent file I'm getting this error now:

```
-bash: ./simple-agent: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```


Actually, the ^M character is just a Windows character, I ran dos2unix and now the file should have no weird characters, I tested it again and it gives me the same errors as before (Illegal instruction) even after giving it executing permissions.

Comment: That [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233442/automate-bluetooth-pairing-trusting-in-bluez5) is for simple pairing which is not relevant for you. Instead, you need to modify the `RequestPasskey` function in `simple-agent`. The problem of not being able to run `simple-agent` appears to be a different issue. Have you check the file permissions?

Comment: I gave it execute permissions but now it's giving me this error: `-bash: ./simple-agent: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, I checked and python exists in the directory /usr/bin, also, the file simple-agent contains the first file `#!/usr/bin/python` but there is no ^M anywhere, I'm not sure if there is any weird characters or something, I'm using nano to edit the file directly in the raspberry pi.

Comment: My bad, apparently the ^M character is part of the Windows new line character, I run dos2unix to remove all those characters and now the file is giving the error `Illegal instruction` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ask separately about the `Illegal instruction` issue on StackOverflow:

[Python Illegal instruction on Raspberry Pi Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748358/python-illegal-instruction-on-raspberry-pi-zero/37749956#37749956)

So I solved that error, it was caused by packages installed that were compiled for a different architecture so I reinstalled everything with `apt-get` and now the script works.

The next thing to do is make sure I can pair the devices with the PIN 0000 which is the main reason I created this question. So I ran the script then I tried to pair it with my computer and it asked for a PIN, I introduced 0000 and it worked!